# Sorting an array of classes in c++

Tags: c++, function, class, sorting

I have 2 classes:

```
class explanations
{
    public:
        int n_size = 0;
        factor reason[20];
        int repetitions = 0;
        double confidence_ratio = 0;
};


class explanations_list
{
    public:
        explanations _list [1000];
        int explanations_counter = 0;
        int times_happened = 0;
};
```

I'm creating an instance of the class `explanations_list`, and I want to create a function that orders the array `_list[1000]` of type `explanations` by `confidence_ratio` (which is contained in the class `explanations`), (in this case using bubble-sort), so it's double.
to do this, I tried to add a function, so the class `explanation_list` becomes:

```
class explanations_list
{
    public:
        explanations _list [1000];
        int explanations_counter = 0;
        int times_happened = 0;

        void order_by_ratio()
        {
            explanations temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000-2; i ++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 1000-1; j++)
                {
                    if (_list[j].confidence_ratio > _list[j+1].confidence_ratio)
                    {
                        temp = _list[j];
                        _list[j] = _list[j+1];
                        _list[j+1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
};
```

But if I create an instance `explanations_list instance1;`

and then run the function `instance1.order_by_ratio();`

it resets all the values, this data structure works and it shows all the info I need, but If I call this function, and then output the values, they all become 0;

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you actually adding any data to `instance1`? If you instantiate it like `explanations_list instance1;` and don't alter the array, then your array will be pointing at junk data when the function is called... junk data == undefined behavior. [Example here](http://ideone.com/84hJoB).

Comment: yes, in reality I'm using an array of "explanations_list", but I didn't include it here to make it simpler. I am adding data to my array of explanations_list, it's not giving me problems, because I'm using counters for the amount of data in the arrays that I'm using

Comment: Doubt it'll solve the issue, but removing `temp` and replacing the inner-most part of your nested loop with `std::swap(_list[j],_list[j+1]);` would be cleaner. You'll need to `#include <utility>`

Comment: Why are you using C arrays rather than a C++ container like `std::array`? Is that an actual bubble sort in the middle there?

Comment: Seconding the suggestion made by @tadman - C arrays are messy (and this is C++ - you have the STL at your disposal). [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) might work rather nicely for you if the number of `explanations` in the `explanations_list` varies.

Comment: "tadam" and "Conduit", your suggestions are amazing! in fact I just had a look at the differences and vectors "can be copied/assigned (this performs a deep copy of all the stored elements)", This will make everything easier, I'll try to switch to vectors and see what happens

Comment: I changed the array declarations into vectors, and changed the order of the sorting, and everything went smooth! now it works, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! The standard template library has containers for pretty much any use case - definitely worth looking over when doing the initial design for any project. The documentation at [this website](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/) (under 'containers') is a good starting point.

Comment: Related note: [the <algorithm> header](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) has many functions explicitly designed to work with STL containers, including sorting functions, that are optimized by better programmers than you or I... Faster speed, and less development time is usually a winner.